# Can we make a @Scheduled execution on Spring, mixed with cron parameter, forcing a first execution at boot time?

Tags: spring, cron, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I made many searches over internet about an option mentioned by Baeldung [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions#cron-special-strings), but I can't find any example. I would like to use something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron="@reboot")
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 5 * * *")
public void somethingToDoOnRebootTime() {
  // code here, to run every day at 5a.m., AND at boot first time... 
}
```

But it didn't work, 'cause "@reboot" is not a valid cron expression... I tried to use this "@reboot" as a normal annotation to the method, but it didn't exists too...

Someone can help me? Is the article on Baeldung wrong?

Comment: Create an `ApplicationListener` which upon an even `ContextRefreshedEvent` triggers that method.

Comment: Almost that, @M.Deinum! I used ApplicationListener but with ApplicationReadyEvent!

Comment: You didn't mention Spring Boot in your question and without Spring Boot that event isn't present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @M.Deinum comment... I used ApplicationListener but with ApplicationReadyEvent! So, my example becames:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 5 * * *")
public void somethingToDoOnRebootTime() {
  // code here, to run every day at 5a.m., AND at boot first time... 
}
```